# How many different words can be formed with all the letters of the word "INTERNET" if each word is to begin with vowel?

Tags: permutations

Plead help me to figure out the solution! According to the book it's answer is 1890. Please help me!

Comment: Hint: write all the solutions for the word `INTE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of [anagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) of the word INTERNET is
$$\frac{8!}{2!\cdot 2! \cdot 2!}=5040$$
because there are 8 letters with 2 Ns, 2 Es and 2 Ts.

How many of them begin with a vowel?

Now the first letter can be chosen in $3$ ways and the remaining places can be filled in $(8-1)!$ ways. Hence, in the above fraction, we replace $8!$ with  $3\cdot 7!$:
$$\frac{3\cdot 7!}{2!\cdot 2! \cdot 2!}=1890.$$

Comment: LOL! I forgot to tick as answered! LOL! You wrote the full answer but I have done it already ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you have n objects with similar objects that are in groups of $k_1,k_2,..,k_r$ such that $k_1+k_2+..+k_r=n$ the number of permutations is given by $$\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!..k_r!}$$
Here you have 1-I, 2-N, 2-T, 2-E, and 1-R

Two vowels are I and E

If first letter is I then there are $$\frac{7!}{2!2!2!}=630$$
If first letter is E then there remaining letters are 1-I, 2-N, 2-T, 1-E, and 1-R  $$\frac{7!}{2!2!}=1260$$
Total $1890$